# "using" keyword when defining member functions and non-member functions

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

Does the "using" keyword have different effects in the context of defining member and non-member functions? The example code below suggests to me that it might.

main.cpp

```
  #include "baz.h"
  int main()
  {
      foo::bar x;
      x.baz();
      foo::foo_non_member();
  }
```

baz.h

```
  namespace foo
  {
      class bar
      {
      public:
          bar() = default;
          void baz();
      };

      void foo_non_member();
  };
```

baz.cpp

```
  #include "baz.h"
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace foo;
  void bar::baz()
  {
      std::cout << "baz\n";
  }

  namespace foo
  {
  void foo_non_member()
  {
      std::cout << "non-member\n";
  }
  }
```

The above code compiles and runs.

```
$> g++ main.cpp baz.cpp; ./a.out
baz
non-member
```

If I remove the `using namespace foo;` from baz.cpp, I get a compiler error.

```
$> g++ main.cpp baz.cpp
baz.cpp:5:6: error: ‘bar’ has not been declared
 void bar::baz()
```

If I put that `using` statement back in and move the definition of `foo_non_member()` outside of the `foo` namespace, I get a linker error.

```
$> g++ main.cpp baz.cpp
/tmp/ccHeSwsZ.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `foo::foo_non_member()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does the `using` keyword appear not to have the same effect here for `bar::baz()` and `foo_non_member()`?

Comment: It absolutely has the exact same effect on every name declared in `namespace foo`. Where do you see different effects? What did you expect instead of the results you've got?

Comment: When `foo_non_member()` is defined outside the explicit namespace block, I get a linker error. When `bar::baz()` is defined outside the explicit namespace block, I don't get a linker error.

Comment: When a name is used, it is looked up in one or more namespaces. When a name is declared or defined, it is not looked up anywhere, it gets introduced in the namespace it is declared in. `bar` is used, not defined or declared, so it needs to be looked up. `foo_non_member` is being defined, so it is not looked up, it is defined where it is.

Comment: "That's because it doesn't get to the linker stage obviously." Yes, it does. If I leave it outside of the explicit namespace block and leave in the `using` statement, it compiles, links, and runs.

Comment: Sorry too many variants, with or without using, in or out of a namespace block. Which one is surprising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this part:

```
using namespace foo;
void bar::baz()
{
   std::cout << "baz\n";
}
```

The `using namespace foo;` is used for the lookup of the `bar::` part, and due to that the compiler is able to tie the definition of `void bar::baz()` to the declaration in the namespace `foo`.
And if you remove `using namespace foo;` it is not able to find `bar`.

> If I put that using statement back in and move the definition of foo_non_member() outside of the foo namespace, I get a linker error.

```
void foo_non_member()
{
   std::cout << "non-member\n";
}
```

Here `foo_non_member` not have any relation to `bar::` or anything else (according to the specs) that would allow the compiler to figure out that this definition is related to the declaration in the namespace `foo`.

The standard committee for sure could have added some rules to the specification to allow the compiler to get the `foo_non_member` definition and the declaration together if the `using namespace foo;` is present but they decided to don't do so.

The reason for that is likely because you then would have the ambiguity about whether you want to define a new `void foo_non_member()` outside of the namespace `foo` or if you want to have a definition for `void foo_non_member()` of `foo`.